# Fill missing values in a column of a dataframe based on a second column in Pyspark

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Basically, let's say I have a dataframe like following:

| RegNum | Name+BirthDate | subscriptionid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Joe-1990/01/01 | 1 |
| 01 | Joe-1990/01/01 | 2 |
| Null | Joe-1990/01/01 | 3 |
| 20 | Joe-2000/12/31 | 4 |
| Null | Joe-2000/12/31 | 5 |
| Null | Joe-2000/12/31 | 6 |

This is very simplified of course, but the main principle in my dataframe is that there are multiple persons (that can have same name, so I distinct them with the birth date) and each row should represent a subscriptionID (one can have several subscriptions)

Now, the regnum column is a quite important one, but it can happen that it is null for some rows, while for other rows of the same person it won't be null.

How can I fill in the Null values of the first column, based on the second one so that I would end up with 6 rows and no null values?

Comment: What logic do you want to use to fill the null values? It is unclear. Alternatively you can use the ``fillna()`` function to fill null values.

Comment: @JAdel Sorry if it was unclear. I would like to fill them in with the regnum that is available for the same "Name+BirthDate". This would give an output of the first column like: 01,01,01,20,20,20

Answer (score 0):

You can use for exemple a Window Function:

```
# Your Dataframe:

df  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
('01','Joe-1990/01/01','1'),
('01','Joe-1990/01/01','2'),
('Null','Joe-1990/01/01','3'),
('20','Joe-2000/12/31','4'),
('Null','Joe-2000/12/31','5'),
('Null','Joe-2000/12/31','6')
  ], ['RegNum','Name+BirthDate','subscriptionid']
)

+------+--------------+--------------+
|RegNum|Name+BirthDate|subscriptionid|
+------+--------------+--------------+
|    01|Joe-1990/01/01|             1|
|    01|Joe-1990/01/01|             2|
|  Null|Joe-1990/01/01|             3|
|    20|Joe-2000/12/31|             4|
|  Null|Joe-2000/12/31|             5|
|  Null|Joe-2000/12/31|             6|
+------+--------------+--------------+
```

Then, using function `first`with `ignorenulls=True` it will pick the first non-null value

```
from pyspark.sql import Window as W
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = W.partitionBy('Name+BirthDate')

df\
    .withColumn('RegNum', F.first('RegNum', True).over(w))\
    .show()

+------+--------------+--------------+
|RegNum|Name+BirthDate|subscriptionid|
+------+--------------+--------------+
|    01|Joe-1990/01/01|             1|
|    01|Joe-1990/01/01|             2|
|    01|Joe-1990/01/01|             3|
|    20|Joe-2000/12/31|             4|
|    20|Joe-2000/12/31|             5|
|    20|Joe-2000/12/31|             6|
+------+--------------+--------------+
```